# how to make sure first command finishes and then only execute second command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

how to make sure first command finishes and then only execute second command in shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Stopping application"
#command to stop application

echo "Starting application"
#command to start application
```

In above code, I wanted to make sure that command to stop application is finished properly and then only start the application.

How to handle this.

Please note in my case if application is already stopped then command to stop application takes some random time to complete i.e. 20sec, 30 sec .
So adding sleep is not proper way.

Main moto behind script is to restart application.
Considering fact that if application is allready stopped it doesnt work properly.

If application is running then the script works perfect.

Comment: How do *you* know that the command to stop application is finished properly? "if application is already stopped then command to stop application takes some random time" Then there's a bug in the command that stops the application.

Comment: Needs more details. Most of the time an application returns 0 after a successful execution or nonzero otherwise but some just return 0 anyway, and sometimes you would have to rely on other things like application output or tangible results like processed files. We can't guess this.

Comment: What do you mean by _finished properly_, as opposed to just _finished_? Also, you did not show which command you used to stop your application. Finally, make up your mind whether you want to run your script by _bash_ or by _sh_; it does not make sense to tag it with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command return code and a condition to do this.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Stopping application"
#command to stop application
rc=$?

# if the stop command was executed successfuly
if [ $rc == 0 ]; then 
    echo "Starting application"
    #command to start application
else
    echo "ERROR - return code: $rc"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @Mozart Sindeaux Neto, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 'exit codes', try this:

```
ls
...

echo $?
0
```

than:

```
ls non_existing_file
ls: cannot access 'non_existing_file': No such file or directory

echo $?
2
```

This command `echo $?` prints exit code of previous command, if it's 0 than it's OK, all non 0 codes means some kind of error which is not OK.